# How to multiple insert in ci in the same table in database

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter

I have a two table to be inserted, I want to insert two times in every in each table. But in my code the only first amount will be inserted. Can you give me an advice on what should i do because I'm not really good in CI.

Here is my **controller**

```
function addloads(){
    $data = array(
        'member' => $this->input->post('member'),
        'cell_number' => $this->input->post('cell_number'),
        'amount' => $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('amount')),
        'total' => $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('total')),
        'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
        'added_by' => $this->session->userdata('admin_id'),
        'date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
        'after_rebate' => $this->input->post('rebate'),
        );


    $this->db->where('mem_id',$this->input->post('member'));
    $this->db->insert('loading_service',$data);

    $status = $this->input->post('status');

    if($status == 'paid'){

        $data2 = array(
            'incomefrom_id' => $this->input->post('member'),
            'income_name' => 'Load',
            'date_created' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
            );

        $this->db->set('time_created', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('incomefrom',$data2);

        $amount = $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('amount'));
        $total = $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('total'));

        $all = $total - $amount;

        $data3 = array(
            'amount' => $all,
            'incomefrom' => $this->input->post('member'),
            'trans_date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
            );
        $this->db->set('trans_time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('income',$data3);



        $amount = $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('amount'));
        $after = $this->parseAmount($this->input->post('rebate'));

        $income = $amount - $after;

        $data9 = array(
            'amount' => $income,
            'incomefrom' => $this->input->post('member'),
            'trans_date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
            );
        $this->db->set('trans_time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('income',$data9);

        $data10 = array(
            'incomefrom_id' => $this->input->post('member'),
            'income_name' => 'Rebate',
            'date_created' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
            );

        $this->db->set('time_created', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('incomefrom',$data10);
    }

    //$this->load->view('loadingservice',$data);
    //redirect(base_url('loadscontroller/loadingserviceview'));
}
```

And this is my **view**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('loadscontroller/addloads') ?>" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group" id="member_form">
                        <label for="member">Member</label>
                         <?php
                            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE mem_is_deleted='0' ORDER BY mem_fname ASC ");
                            if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
                            $select= '<select class="form-control" id="member" name="member" required >';
                            while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['mem_id'].'">'.$rs['mem_fname'].' ' .$rs['mem_lname'].'</option>';
                              }
                            }
                            $select.='</select>';
                            echo $select;
                        ?>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger" id="member_err"></p>



                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="cell_number">
                        <label for="cell_number">Cellphone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell_number" name="cell_number" placeholder="" required>
                        <!-- <p class="help-block text-danger" id="grossamount_err"></p> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" value="5" hidden>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="00" required onkeyup="sum();">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--  <div class="row" id="willsend" style="display:none">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Will send <span id="lblnet"></span> to <span id="lblbaccountname"></span> <span id="lblbaccount"></span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="total">Total</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="00" required >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- <label for="total">With Rebate</label> -->
                        <input type="text" id="rebate" name="rebate" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group" style="width: 200px;">
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control readonly datepicker" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('F d, Y') ?>" required readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group" id="status">
                <label for="status">Status</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required style="width: 150px;">
                        <option selected="" value="">--select--</option>
                        <option value="paid">PAID</option>
                        <option value="unpaid">UNPAID</option>
                    </select>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <!-- /.row -->
        </form>
```

Comment: Firstly, why are you using native mysql_* functions in the view? These queries should be in a model, called from your controller and passed as a var directly into your view. Also use the CI active record set classes, they make everything much safer. Secondly, I don't think you can use the `set` method when doing an insert. Set is generally used when doing an UPDATE in mysql, I might be wrong but I have never seen it used in that way.

Comment: @mic is correct. no database calls in the view. use codeigniter active record. your addloads() method in the controller is trying to do too many different things. take the time to work through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual so you learn the basics.

Comment: i want an answer on how to insert two data in each table at a time. I used query in my view because its the fastest way to do it. My view functioned.